# What is the mean and variance for this Normal distrbution?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, random-variable, independence

Suppose, we have $X_1,X_2,$ and $X_3$ i.i.d random variables (RV's) from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Let $Y=\frac{X_1-X_2}{2}$, and $W=X_3-Y$.

Then is $W\sim N(0,2\sigma^2)$ or $W\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: Which normal distribution?  You have 3 listed.  Are the $X$'s iid as well or should we assume correlation?  If so, what are the correlations?

Comment: What are $x_1$ and $x_2$ exactly? All pairs of values taken i.i.d. from $X$? OR certain values from $X$? Or...

Comment: @StatsStudent They are iids. Sorry, I will revise the question.

Comment: @Bernhard They are iids. Sorry, I will revise the question.

Comment: As is, this is a hopeless mess. Voting to close, pending an explanation of the $X$'s, // Edit didn't help. $X, X_1, X_2$ indep and identically distributed $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\sigma)$ will not lead to either proposed answer.

Comment: This looks like a homework question.  If it is, please add the `self-study` tag and read this:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @StatsStudent It is not homework. I have included the `self-study` tag as suggested.

Comment: Is $X$ in $W$ supposed to be a vector $[X_1, X_2]^T$ or should this be $W=X_1-Y$ or perhaps $W=X_2-Y$?

Comment: You can rule one of them out from basic properties of variances https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties

Comment: @StatsStudent Your question prompted me to rethink the problem formulation. I have revised accordingly. I hope it is more meaningful now.

Comment: @nashynash, I was wondering about that...  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This is the third question you ask on almost an identical issue, please consider the problem on your own before rushing to ask a new question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated based on OP's question revision with $W=X_{3}-Y$.

Assume $W=X_{3}-Y$. Then:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(W) & = & E(X_{3}-Y)\\
 & = & E(X_{3})-E(Y)\\
 & = & E(X_{3})-\frac{E[X_{1}-X_{2}]}{2}\\
 & = & E(X_{3})-\frac{E[X_{1}]}{2}+\frac{E[X_{2}]}{2}\\
 & = & \mu-\frac{\mu}{2}+\frac{\mu}{2}\\
 & = & \mu
\end{eqnarray*}

and because $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are independent we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
V(W) & = & V(X_{3}-Y)\\
 & = & V\left[X_{3}-\frac{(X_{1}-X_{2})}{2}\right]\\
 & = & V\left[X_{3}-\frac{X_{1}}{2}+\frac{X_{2}}{2}\right]\\
 & = & V\left[X_{3}-\frac{X_{1}}{2}+\frac{X_{2}}{2}\right]\\
 & = & V(X_{3})+\frac{V(X_{1})}{4}+\frac{V(X_{2})}{4}\\
 & = & \sigma^{2}+\frac{\sigma^{2}+\sigma^{2}}{4}\\
 & = & \frac{4\sigma^{2}}{4}+\frac{2\sigma^{2}}{4}\\
 & = & \frac{3\sigma^{2}}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

We know that linear transformations of normal random variables is
also a normal. Since $W$ is a linear transformation, we have $W\sim N(\mu,\frac{3\sigma^{2}}{2})$

Comment: Thank you very much.